# Module 'tensorflow._api.v1.compat.v1.compat' has no attribute 'v1' in Google Colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, conda, google-colaboratory

I am trying to implement the training model from https://github.com/tensorflow/compression/tree/master/models/hific in Google Colab. For compatibility issues, I've created a Conda environment with Python 3.7 as shown in the description page. However, when training my model I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/envs/hific/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/local/envs/hific/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/content/compression/models/hific/train.py", line 137, in <module>
    main(parse_args(sys.argv))
  File "/content/compression/models/hific/train.py", line 133, in main
    helpers.parse_tfds_arguments(args))
  File "/content/compression/models/hific/train.py", line 45, in train
    hific.build_model(**get_next)
  File "/content/compression/models/hific/model.py", line 393, in build_model
    self._lpips_loss = LPIPSLoss(self._lpips_weight_path)
  File "/content/compression/models/hific/model.py", line 857, in __init__
    graph_def = tf.compat.v1.GraphDef()
  File "/usr/local/envs/hific/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/util/module_wrapper.py", line 193, in __getattr__
    attr = getattr(self._tfmw_wrapped_module, name)
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v1.compat.v1.compat' has no attribute 'v1'
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/envs/hific/lib/python3.7/site-packages/compare_gan/architectures/abstract_arch.py:71: The name tf.AUTO_REUSE is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.AUTO_REUSE instead.
```

These are the packages installed in the conda environment:

```
# packages in environment at /usr/local/envs/hific:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                 conda_forge    conda-forge
_openmp_mutex             4.5                       2_gnu    conda-forge
absl-py                   1.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
astor                     0.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
ca-certificates           2023.11.17           hbcca054_0    conda-forge
certifi                   2023.11.17               pypi_0    pypi
charset-normalizer        3.3.2                    pypi_0    pypi
compare-gan               3.0                      pypi_0    pypi
cudatoolkit               10.0.130            h9ed11e1_12    conda-forge
cudnn                     7.6.5.32             ha8d7eb6_1    conda-forge
cycler                    0.11.0                   pypi_0    pypi
enum34                    1.1.10                   pypi_0    pypi
fonttools                 4.38.0                   pypi_0    pypi
future                    0.18.3                   pypi_0    pypi
gast                      0.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
gin-config                0.1.4                    pypi_0    pypi
google-pasta              0.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
googleapis-common-protos  1.62.0                   pypi_0    pypi
grpcio                    1.60.0                   pypi_0    pypi
h5py                      2.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
idna                      3.6                      pypi_0    pypi
importlib-metadata        6.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
keras                     2.1.6                    pypi_0    pypi
keras-applications        1.0.8                    pypi_0    pypi
keras-preprocessing       1.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
kiwisolver                1.4.5                    pypi_0    pypi
ld_impl_linux-64          2.40                 h41732ed_0    conda-forge
libffi                    3.4.2                h7f98852_5    conda-forge
libgcc-ng                 13.2.0               h807b86a_3    conda-forge
libgomp                   13.2.0               h807b86a_3    conda-forge
libnsl                    2.0.1                hd590300_0    conda-forge
libsqlite                 3.44.2               h2797004_0    conda-forge
libstdcxx-ng              13.2.0               h7e041cc_3    conda-forge
libzlib                   1.2.13               hd590300_5    conda-forge
markdown                  3.4.4                    pypi_0    pypi
markupsafe                2.1.3                    pypi_0    pypi
matplotlib                3.5.3                    pypi_0    pypi
ncurses                   6.4                  h59595ed_2    conda-forge
numpy                     1.18.5                   pypi_0    pypi
openssl                   3.2.0                hd590300_1    conda-forge
opt-einsum                3.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
packaging                 23.2                     pypi_0    pypi
pandas                    1.3.5                    pypi_0    pypi
pillow                    8.3.2                    pypi_0    pypi
pip                       23.3.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
promise                   2.3                      pypi_0    pypi
protobuf                  3.20.3                   pypi_0    pypi
pstar                     0.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pyparsing                 3.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
python                    3.7.12          hf930737_100_cpython    conda-forge
python-dateutil           2.8.2                    pypi_0    pypi
pytz                      2023.3.post1             pypi_0    pypi
pyyaml                    6.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
qj                        0.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
readline                  8.2                  h8228510_1    conda-forge
requests                  2.31.0                   pypi_0    pypi
scipy                     1.7.3                    pypi_0    pypi
setuptools                69.0.3             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
six                       1.16.0                   pypi_0    pypi
sqlite                    3.44.2               h2c6b66d_0    conda-forge
tensorboard               1.15.0                   pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow                1.15.0                   pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-compression    1.3                      pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-datasets       1.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-estimator      1.15.1                   pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-gan            0.0.0.dev0               pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-gpu            1.15.5                   pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-hub            0.15.0                   pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-metadata       1.12.0                   pypi_0    pypi
termcolor                 2.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tk                        8.6.13          noxft_h4845f30_101    conda-forge
tqdm                      4.66.1                   pypi_0    pypi
typing-extensions         4.7.1                    pypi_0    pypi
urllib3                   2.0.7                    pypi_0    pypi
werkzeug                  2.2.3                    pypi_0    pypi
wheel                     0.42.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
wrapt                     1.16.0                   pypi_0    pypi
xz                        5.2.6                h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
zipp                      3.15.0                   pypi_0    pypi
```

And these are the requirements as from github:

```
CUDA 10.0
Python 3.6-3.7
TensorFlow 1.15

from requirements.txt:
git+https://github.com/google/compare_gan@19922d3004b675c1a49c4d7515c06f6f75acdcc8
tensorflow-gpu~=1.15.2
tensorflow-compression==1.3
Pillow~=8.3.2
```